# Can I ask all the apps available for an specific purpose provided I don't ask which one is the best?

Tags: discussion

According to the FAQ, these questions are disallowed:

> Questions that are primarily opinion-based, such as device or app recommendations or speculative questions

I understand that asking "which notes app should I use?" is a poor question because it is entirely subjective, because different people will have different criteria of why you *should* or *should not* use a certain app.

But consider a question like this:

> ## What apps are there to make toast with Android?
>
> I need to make toast using my smartphone, but I don't know where to look and Google isn't helpful.
>
> Criteria:
>
> - Has to make toast
> - Opensource
> - No ads
> - Relatively relevant (at the very least 10,000 downloads)

It isn't opinion-based, it is asking for all apps that there are, given that they fulfill the given criteria. Would it still be unfit for Android.SE?

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic which has more detail -- short version is that *all* recommendation questions are off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. That's still a "list question". There could be a dozen apps that do that. Which one is the "right" app?

If you have a specific use case and platform criteria, your question should be okay at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). I currently see well over 900 questions there tagged [`android`](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: Full ack. But before posting on SR, make sure you've read [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) Quite strict rules over there :)